# make multiple rest api calls and combine the result using c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api2

Here is the scenario where I need help.

- User enters keyword and hit search
- I am providing that keyword to multiple APIs in order to get the results using httpclient request.
- I am getting response based on search keyword from different APIs.

But the issue is I am making search calls one by one to these apis. I want to do something where once user hits search it makes call to all the APIs at once and then combine the results.

```
WalmartModel model=new WalmartModel();

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("**URL 1**");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    //GET Method  
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<WalmartModel>();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
    }                
}


using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("**URL 2**");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    //GET Method  
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<WalmartModel>();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
    }                
}
```

once I get the result I am combining the list and returning it.(which I don't think is a best practice to follow.)

I know I can utilize multitasking threads but i have no practical examples to follow. Can anyone suggest the best approach to handle this ?

Comment: Multiple requests in parallel and combine the results. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: At least provide some code with how you do that now.

Comment: This would be an answerable question if you provided some code to show how you are currently making the API calls. "multitasking threads " would not be the right approach.

Comment: So [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703(v=vs.110).aspx) answers your question perfectly.

Comment: @spender  this is how i am doing it right now. Making calls one after another to multiple APIs and combining results at the end. which will become very time consuming process if i had to call multiple APIs.

Comment: @SachinTrivedi, Encapsulate the call into an async function and use `Task.WhenAll` to collect all the results

Comment: @SachinTrivedi Your code is different. You are awaiting each call in turn before starting the next download. The article launches all of the download tasks before any awaiting is done.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an approach you can take.

Encapsulate the calls to the different APIs into async functions that return a common model. In this case a common method that will return `WalmartModel` after querying a URL.

```
public async Task<WalmartModel> GetModel(string url, HttpClient client) {
    //GET Method  
    using(var response = await client.GetAsync(url)) {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<WalmartModel>();
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
        }
    }         
    return null;       
}
```

Use `Task.WhenAll` to *await* all the API searches and collect the results when they complete

```
//Using a single client to make the calls.
using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    //create the search tasks to be executed
    var tasks = new []{
        GetModel("**URL 1**", client),
        GetModel("**URL 2**", client),
        GetModel("**URL N**", client),
    };

    // Await the completion of all the running tasks. 
    var responses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // returns IEmumerable<WalmartModel>

    var results = responses.Where(r => r != null); //filter out any null values
}
```

`Task.WhenAll` returns a single task that finishes when all the tasks in the collection of tasks have completed.

Comment: I will surely try this out and let you know. Thanks for putting out this code.

Comment: I am calling different APIs which returns different responses in json. How do i combine the json response from them into one format ? i.e I am calling walmart and best buy apis